# code ran into segmentation fault error.how to fix?

Tags: c

The attached image is the code on hackerrank for a problem i dont know why but it runs into segmentation fault error.Please help me to fix this problem.[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezoLQ.png)
The error shown is in this link[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKWky.png)

Comment: Type the code and paste it. In fact paste it from the IDE of hackerrank direclty here --`i<(i+m)` is wrong - moving condition never stops leading to seg fault.

Comment: do not post a link to an image of the code, Rather post the actual text of the code into the question itself.  (indent all lines of the code an extra 4 spaces so it will be formatted as CODE rather than TEXT

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value, (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: it is very poor programming practice to `#include` header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest remove: `#include <assert.h>` and `#include <limits.h>` and `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: what can i do in place of i<i+m

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  Variable names like `s_i`, `x`, `m`, etc are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: regarding: `for(i;i<(i+m);i++)` will never exit unless `m` is <= 0 the result is the code loops until runnoff the end of the array `s[]`  This quickly results in undefined behavior, and leads to the seg fault event.   Perhaps you meant: `for( ; (i+m) < n; i++ )`  note: the original  statement will not compile.  The compiler will output a message that the first parameter does nothing.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( for if else while do...while switch case default ) via a single blank line. 2) follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.   3) insert appropriate space after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, around C operators

Comment: is the problem expecting to read from a file or from the user?   Without checking the returned value from calls to `scanf()` how are you expecting the code to handle a EOF event?

Comment: it is good programming practice to limit the 'scope' of variables.  So this statement: `while( x<=m)`  (and related statements) would be better written as: `for( int x=m; x<n; x+=m)`

Comment: in C, the valid index into an array is 0...(number of items in array -1) So, even if the rest of the code were 'ok' (which it is not) this statement: `while(x<=n)` will cause the code to access beyond the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the linked code does not solve the problem set.  Amongst other things, it does not allow for overlapping ranges (as expressed in the original problem scenario.

Answer (score 1):

in the for-loop line 24, the condition is set to `i < (i+m)`. If `m` is a positive integer, than the condition will always be true, therefore `s[i]` will at some point access memory that it shouldn't.

Comment: but this loop is under while loop so that condition won't occur at all

Comment: `for(i ; i<(i+m);i++)` the code in this loop will run as long as the condition `i<i+m` is true. It will always be true if m>0. therefore `i` will be increased beyond `n`. 
Use your debugger !